# C++ parse, fetch a variable number of integers from a string

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I have a set of strings which looks like 
*"4 7 14 0 2 blablabla"* 
*"3 8 1 40 blablablablabla"* 
*...*

The first number N correspond to how many numbers will follow.
Basically, the format of a string is N+1 numbers, separated with a space, followed by an unknown number of irrelevant characters at the end that I don't need.

How can I get all the numbers in variables or a dynamic structure given that I don't know the number N in advance ?

In other words, I'd like something like:

```
sscanf(s, "%d %d %d %d",&n,&x,&y,&z);
```

which would work no matter how many numbers in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int input;
std::vector<int> ints;
while(std::cin >>  input)  //read as long as there is integer
       ints.push_back(input);
std::cin.clear(); //clear the error flag
//read the remaining input which most certainly is non-integer
```

Comment: Hum, I'm not sure this answers the OP question: what if the input string is `2 7 9 14 23 foo bar`? Only `7` and `9` should be read, and `14`, `23`, `foo` and `bar` ignored.

Comment: But of course, using `std::vector` and streams is the way to go!

Comment: Right, but then you know ints[0], the number of relevant integers so it's no big deal. Certainly not an optimized solution but concise and elegant answer that shows the way to go :) but thank you all for your answers very helpful

Comment: @piouk: If you want conciseness, you can even replace the loop with a call to `copy_n`: `int N; input >> N; std::vector<int> ints; copy_n( istream_iterator<int>( input), N, back_inserter( ints ) );`

Comment: @LucTouraille: Why even `copy_n`? He can use the constructor itself as : `std::vector<int> ints((istream_iterator<int>(cin)), istream_iterator<int>());`

Comment: Sure, `copy_n` is only useful to read only the N first numbers.

Answer (score 6):

The first thing would be to break up the input into lines, by using
`getline` to read it.  This will greatly facilitate error recovery and 
resynchronization in case of error.  It will also facilitate parsing;
it's the strategy which should be adopted almost every time a newline in
the input is significant.  After that, you use a `std::istringstream` to
parse the line.  Something like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > data;
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( input, line ) ) {
    std::istringstream l( line );
    int iCount;
    l >> iCount;
    if ( !l || iCount < 0 ) {
        //  format error: line doesn't start with an int.
    } else {
        std::vector<int> lineData;
        int value;
        while ( lineData.size() != iCount && l >> value ) {
            lineData.push_back( value ) ;
        }
        if ( lineData.size() == iCount ) {
            data.push_back( lineData );
        } else {
            //  format error: line didn't contain the correct
            //  number of ints
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string s = "3 54 -4 42 fdsvadsdsberwte";
std::istringstream source(s);

std::vector<int> ints;

int num = 0;
int temp = 0;

if (source >> num)  // read the first number and if it succeeds, read the rest
{
    while(source >> temp) ints.push_back(temp);
    // Here, I'd compare the size of the vector with what was
    // expected (num) and act accordingly.
}
else
{
     // format error 
}
```

Comment: +1 Excellent answer.  You might have mentionned `getline` to  get the individual strings, but for the rest... It's nice to see someone mention the fact that you have to check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an [`istringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/istringstream/) with your string, and read from it:

```
std::istringstream ss(s);

int N;
ss >> N;

std::vector<int> a(N); //int* a = new int[N];
for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    ss >> a[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it something like this:

```
std::string buffer;
while(std::getline(in, buffer)) {    // read a line
    std::istringstream str(buffer);  // put line in a stringstream for parsing
    int count;
    str >> count;                    // read first number
    std::vector<int> numbers(count); // reserve space for other numbers
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) { // read other numbers
        str >> numbers[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic array and a linked list, of dynamic array type. After reading a line initialize the array using number N and insert the numbers sequentially on each index. Insert the node containing line data to linked list.

Pseudo code:

```
int *lineNumbers;
lineNumbers = new int[N];

List<int*> data;
data.insert(lineNumbers);
```